# How can i fix my problem with CSS in my React?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

anybody knows why my css file doesn't work on my React?

this is the header.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import './index.css';
import App from './App'; 
import * as reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode> 
    <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

this is my index.css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}

.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.task {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.task.reminder {
  border-left: 5px solid green;
}

.task h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.add-form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.form-control {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.form-control label {
  display: block;
}

.form-control input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.form-control-check {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-control-check label {
  flex: 1;
}

.form-control-check input {
  flex: 2;
  height: 20px;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

my index.css and my header.js is inside my componennts folder and my components folder is inside my src folder.
if it works well, a border should appear around the "Task Tracker" text but it doesn't...

Comment: Have you set a css loader in your bundler config? There is not enough to go on here for us to help you.

Comment: what is css loader? i guess not

Comment: and how can and where i put the css loader? im just a begginer...